# Does not contain a definition for 'WhenAll' Mvc 4 .Net framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have .Net Framework 4.0 and I've installed [Microsoft Async 1.0.168](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.168) and my code is:

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> Search(string searchKey)
{
        var tasks = new Task[3];
        int i = 0;

        SearchModel viewModel = new SearchModel();
        viewModel.SearchKey = searchKey;

        List<Task> TaskList = GetSeachResult(searchKey, viewModel);

        foreach(Task tsk in TaskList)
        {
             tasks[i] = tsk;
             i++;
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        return PartialView("ResultView", viewModel);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [This method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) added with .NET Framework 4.5. Have you consider to upgrade your .NET version?

Comment: Yes,I know.I need to know how can I use instead of Whenall in .Net Framework 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With "Microsoft Async" nuget package you have to use `TaskEx.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WhenAll`.

They have added it in a completely new class named `TaskEx` as you can't add static methods to a type without modifying the source. Starting from .Net 4.5 you can use `Task.WhenAll` and remove the "Microsoft Async" nuget package completely.

Comment: So how can I remove Microsoft async package?

Comment: @Zehra You don't want to remove it as you need it (since you're using .net 4.0 not 4.5)

Comment: infact you're right.But I need to use WhenAll() @Sriram

Comment: @Zehra That's what. Use `TaskEx.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: I did it,but Error 1 The name 'TaskEx' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Strange. If you have installed "Microsoft Async" nuget package it will work. Make sure you have it in place.

Comment: Are you missing a `using` statement perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG I guess no because it is defined in same namespace as `Task` i.e "System.Threading.Tasks" namespace. OP make sure that you have the using statement for  System.Threading.Tasks.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You're right.I uninstalled async after your first comment.I install again .Problem is solved.Thanks !!